# Change textbox value with double click table

Tags: jquery

I need to change the values ​​in my form as soon as I double-click a table row. When i double click in a line of my table, put the id and name inside your respective input text. I have no idea how I can do this.

```html
<input type="text" id="itemID">
<input type="text" id="itemName">

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>NAME</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="dblClick">
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Jace</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="dblClick">
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Jennifer</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Here are the jQuery methods you need to research: http://api.jquery.com/on, http://api.jquery.com/text, http://api.jquery.com/val. Once you've made an attempt and if you still have issues, please edit the question to include the JS code you attempted and we will help you debug the issue. Remember that SO is not here to write code for you.

Comment: Yeah, i know it, i asked expecting a way to start.. thanks btw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Jq this could be done with much less code.

Here i made an example below with only js.

```js
var itemId = document.getElementById("itemID");

var itemName = document.getElementById("itemName");

var tr = document.getElementsByClassName("dblClick");
for(var i = 0; i< tr.length; i++){
 let item = tr[i]
 item.addEventListener("dblclick", ()=> {
    itemId.value = item.children[0].innerHTML
    itemName.value = item.children[1].innerHTML

  });
 }
```

```html
<input type="text" id="itemID">
<input type="text" id="itemName">

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>NAME</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="dblClick">
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Jace</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="dblClick">
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Jennifer</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```